# Is there a general formula for any polynomials of rational, non-integer degree?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are formulae out there for certain integer-degree polynomials; for instance, the general solution for $ax^2+bx+c$ is $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.

Is there a general form equation for, say, $a\sqrt{x}+bx+c$? Or $a\sqrt[3]{x}+b\sqrt{x}+cx+d$? And so on?

Comment: $a\sqrt{x}+bx+c$ technically isn't a polynomial. See <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial> for a definition.

Comment: @Gnumbertester So what would it be? Just a function?

Comment: Sometimes it makes sense to rewrite the kinds of equations you illustrate by making a change of variables that gives us a polynomial.  As far as equations involving a sum of powers that are not whole numbers, there is a generalization of Descartes rule of signs for these, but no general formula for roots.

Comment: The degree of a non-zero polynomial is always an integer. Functions containing $\sqrt{x}$ or other terms different from $ax^n$ with a real number $a$ and a non-negative integer $n$ are not called a polynomial. Note that there is no general formula for polynomials with degree $5$ or higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only general formulas for finding the roots of polynomials up to the $4$th degree. It's been proven that there are no such formulas for all $5$th or higher degree polynomials. The Wikipedia entry [Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial) says:

> In 1824, Niels Henrik Abel proved the striking result that there are equations of degree 5 whose solutions cannot be expressed by a (finite) formula, involving only arithmetic operations and radicals (see Abel–Ruffini theorem). In 1830, Évariste Galois proved that most equations of degree higher than four cannot be solved by radicals, and showed that for each equation, one may decide whether it is solvable by radicals, and, if it is, solve it.

As mentioned by myself and other commenters, such as hardmath, you can convert equations involving rational roots of a variable by using a substitution of the smallest power which will cause all of the powers of this transformed equation to be integral.

Comment: Among integers, yes, but what about rationals in general?

Comment: @DonielF Your rational form equations are basically the same as ones with integers when you make the appropriate substitution. For example, with your $a\sqrt{x} + bx + c$, you can have $y = \sqrt{x}$ to have the equivalent polynomial of $ay + by^2 + c$.

Comment: So... You're saying that the solution to $a\sqrt{x}+bx+c$ is $x^2=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4bc}}{2b}$?

Comment: @DonielF Actually, by "solution", if you mean the roots, then it would be $\sqrt{x}$ on the left side, not $x^2$. Otherwise, you get the idea.

Comment: All $n$th degree polynomials have $n$ roots, although not necessarily real and/or unique. In the case of a quadratic equation, both possibilities are roots. However, some questions have limitations, usually such as requiring integral or positive values, which could mean that one, or even both, of the roots are not valid.

Comment: So the roots, theoretically, are at $x=\frac{a^2+2a\sqrt{a^2-4bc}+a^2-4bc}{4b^2}=\frac{2a^2+2a\sqrt{a^2-4bc}-4bc}{4b^2}=\frac{a^2+a\sqrt{a^2-4bc}-2bc}{2b^2}$? Is my half-asleep brain processing this correctly?

Comment: And then solutions to equations involving $\sqrt[5]{x}$ or greater index wouldn't have a general solution, since there's no solution to polynomials of degree $5$ or greater?

Comment: @DonielF Your equations only show one root, with the values possibly being correct depending on what the coefficients are in your equation, along with what sort of substitution you are using.

Comment: @DonielF Regarding your question involving $\sqrt[5]{x}$, your statement is correct.

Comment: Can I guarantee that when substituting $y=\sqrt{x}$ that I won’t introduce or eliminate any roots?

Comment: @DonielF You won't lose any roots, such as in your example because when you solve for $y$, you can get $x$ uniquely by squaring $y$. In general, if you substitute $y = \sqrt[n]{x}$, of some integer $n \ge 2$, you can get back all values of $x$ from the values of $y$ by taking them to the $n$th power.

Answer (score -3):

I've been tinkering with a similar problem. 
$ ax + b\sqrt x + c$ is part of a class of "polynomials" that can be solved with the quadratic formula that don't look like the typical $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$.
If you name the exponents $d, e,$ and $f,$ the typical equation becomes
$ax^d + bx^e + cx^f = 0,$ with $d = 2, e = 1,$ and $f = 0$.
Any function where $d + f = 2e$ can be solved with the quadratic formula, using the appropriate choices for $a, b,$ and $c$.  The trick is to separate out the non-typical $x$-terms, and include them in the coefficients that go into the quadratic equation.  Call these revised coefficients $a_1, b_1,$ and $c_1$.  In this way one can solve some equations with non-integer, and/or negative exponents:

$2x^{4.1} - 5x^{1.1} + 3x^{-1.9} = 0$
Set $a_1 =  2x^{2.1},  b_1 = -5x^{0.1},  c_1 =  3x^{-1.9}$
Plug $a_1, b_1,$ and $c_1$ into the quadratic equation, and you get $2$ answers, both in terms of x.  With a little more easy algebra, you get (I haven't checked this yet) $6$ answers.  $3$ are the cube roots of $1$, and three are the cube roots of $1.5$.

I'd like to find a trick to get past the $d + f = 2e$ requirement, but I don't see much hope there.  I'd also like to see if this trick works with complex exponents.  I think it should.  But, I don't have time for that.  Maybe somebody out there knows where to find more information on this?